# Error: The configmap "aws-auth" does not exist

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks

I have seen other examples of this error on here, but they haven't resolved my issue, hopefully someone can explain where i have gone wrong.

I am using the aws eks module: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules

I have used the default example from Terraform and appreciate i need to clean up some of the code as not all is wanted, but its still valid code.

This is my module code:

```
module "eks" {
  source                         = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  cluster_name                   = local.name
  cluster_version                = "1.24"
  cluster_endpoint_public_access = true
  cluster_addons = {
    coredns = {
      preserve    = true
      most_recent = true
      timeouts = {
        create = "25m"
        delete = "10m"
      }
    }
    kube-proxy = {
      most_recent = true
    }
    vpc-cni = {
      most_recent = true
    }
  }

  # External encryption key
  create_kms_key = false
  cluster_encryption_config = {
    resources        = ["secrets"]
    provider_key_arn = module.kms.key_arn
  }
  iam_role_additional_policies = {
    additional = aws_iam_policy.additional.arn
  }
  vpc_id                   = data.aws_ssm_parameter.vpc_id.value
  subnet_ids               = split(", ", data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_subnets.value)
  control_plane_subnet_ids = split(", ", data.aws_ssm_parameter.intra_subnets.value)
  # Extend cluster security group rules
  cluster_security_group_additional_rules = {
    ingress_nodes_ephemeral_ports_tcp = {
      description                = "Nodes on ephemeral ports"
      protocol                   = "tcp"
      from_port                  = 1025
      to_port                    = 65535
      type                       = "ingress"
      source_node_security_group = true
    }
    # Test: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/pull/2319
    ingress_source_security_group_id = {
      description              = "Ingress from another computed security group"
      protocol                 = "tcp"
      from_port                = 22
      to_port                  = 22
      type                     = "ingress"
      source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.additional.id
    }
  }
  # Extend node-to-node security group rules
  node_security_group_additional_rules = {
    ingress_self_all = {
      description = "Node to node all ports/protocols"
      protocol    = "-1"
      from_port   = 0
      to_port     = 0
      type        = "ingress"
      self        = true
    }
    # Test: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/pull/2319
    ingress_source_security_group_id = {
      description              = "Ingress from another computed security group"
      protocol                 = "tcp"
      from_port                = 22
      to_port                  = 22
      type                     = "ingress"
      source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.additional.id
    }
  }
  # EKS Managed Node Group(s)
  eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    ami_type                              = "AL2_x86_64"
    instance_types                        = [var.micro_ec2_instance, var.small_ec2_instance, var.medium_ec2_instance, var.large_ec2_instance]
    attach_cluster_primary_security_group = true
    vpc_security_group_ids                = [aws_security_group.additional.id]
    iam_role_additional_policies = {
      additional = aws_iam_policy.additional.arn
    }
  }
  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    blue = {}
    green = {
      min_size       = 1
      max_size       = 10
      desired_size   = 1
      instance_types = ["t3.large"]
      capacity_type  = "SPOT"
      labels = {
        Environment = "test"
        GithubRepo  = "terraform-aws-eks"
        GithubOrg   = "terraform-aws-modules"
      }
      taints = {
        dedicated = {
          key    = "dedicated"
          value  = "gpuGroup"
          effect = "NO_SCHEDULE"
        }
      }
      update_config = {
        max_unavailable_percentage = 33 # or set `max_unavailable`
      }
      tags = {
        ExtraTag = "example"
      }
    }
  }

  # aws-auth configmap
  manage_aws_auth_configmap = true

  aws_auth_node_iam_role_arns_non_windows = [
    module.eks_managed_node_group.iam_role_arn,
    #  module.self_managed_node_group.iam_role_arn,
  ]

  aws_auth_roles = var.map_roles

  tags = local.tags
}

module "eks_managed_node_group" {
  source                            = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws//modules/eks-managed-node-group"
  name                              = "separate-eks-mng"
  cluster_name                      = module.eks.cluster_name
  cluster_version                   = module.eks.cluster_version
  subnet_ids                        = split(", ", data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_subnets.value)
  cluster_primary_security_group_id = module.eks.cluster_primary_security_group_id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    module.eks.cluster_security_group_id,
  ]
  ami_type = "BOTTLEROCKET_x86_64"
  platform = "bottlerocket"
  # this will get added to what AWS provides
  bootstrap_extra_args = <<-EOT
    # extra args added
    [settings.kernel]
    lockdown = "integrity"
    [settings.kubernetes.node-labels]
    "label1" = "foo"
    "label2" = "bar"
  EOT
  tags                 = merge(local.tags, { Separate = "eks-managed-node-group" })
}

module "disabled_eks" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  create = false
}

module "disabled_fargate_profile" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws//modules/fargate-profile"
  create = false
}

module "disabled_eks_managed_node_group" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws//modules/eks-managed-node-group"
  create = false
}

module "disabled_self_managed_node_group" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws//modules/eks-managed-node-group"
  create = false
}

module "kms" {
  source                = "terraform-aws-modules/kms/aws"
  version               = "1.1.0"
  aliases               = ["eks/${var.project}-${var.application}-${local.name}"]
  description           = "${local.name} cluster encryption key"
  enable_default_policy = true
  key_owners            = [data.aws_caller_identity.current.arn]
  tags                  = local.tags
}
```

I understand the issue lies here:

```
  aws_auth_roles = var.map_roles
```

I am passing this variable from my variable.tf file with this:

```
variable "map_roles" {
  description = "List of role maps to add to the aws_auth configmap"
  type = list(object({
    rolearn  = string
    username = string
    groups   = list(string)
  }))

  default = []
}
```

The values for this variable are here:

```
map_roles = [
  {
    rolearn  = "arn:aws:iam::*account_id*:role/QADevelopersRole"
    username = "QADevelopersRole"
    groups   = ["system:masters"]
  },
  {
    rolearn  = "arn:aws:iam::*account_id*:role/QAAdminRole"
    username = "QAAdminRole"
    groups   = ["system:masters"]
  },
  {
    rolearn  = "arn:aws:iam::*account_id*:role/QASreRole"
    username = "QASreRole"
    groups   = ["system:masters"]
  },
  {
    rolearn  = "arn:aws:iam::*account_id*:role/sandbox-eu-west-2-ContinuousDeliverySlavesRole"
    username = "sandbox-eu-west-2-ContinuousDeliverySlavesRole"
    groups   = ["system:masters"]
  }
]
```

NOTE: I deliberately haven't shared my account id

I can run a terraform init fine. However, when i run a terraform plan i get the following error:

```
Plan: 1 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
module.kms.aws_kms_key.this[0]: Modifying... [id=51a16f6d-fd34-4f79-b750-1e5aee6cb1a8]
module.eks.kubernetes_config_map_v1_data.aws_auth[0]: Creating...
module.kms.aws_kms_key.this[0]: Modifications complete after 5s [id=51a16f6d-fd34-4f79-b750-1e5aee6cb1a8]

Error: The configmap "aws-auth" does not exist

  with module.eks.kubernetes_config_map_v1_data.aws_auth[0],
  on .terraform/modules/eks/main.tf line 527, in resource "kubernetes_config_map_v1_data" "aws_auth":
 527: resource "kubernetes_config_map_v1_data" "aws_auth" {

make: *** [deploy] Error 1
```

My understanding is that the module should create all the kubernetes configuration required automatically, including the configmap.

When running the apply, the following out is generated:

```
Validating terraform code.
Success! The configuration is valid.

Deploying the infrastructure on ** 20_eks_cluster **
module.eks.module.kms.data.aws_partition.current: Reading...
data.aws_ssm_parameter.public_subnet_2: Reading...
data.aws_ssm_parameter.public_subnet_3: Reading...
aws_iam_policy.additional: Refreshing state... [id=arn:aws:iam::*accountid*:policy/qa-k8s-poc-Cluster-additional]
module.disabled_eks.module.kms.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Reading...
data.aws_ssm_parameter.public_subnets: Reading...
module.eks.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Reading...
module.eks.data.aws_partition.current: Reading...
data.aws_ssm_parameter.intra_subnet_2: Reading...
module.eks.module.kms.data.aws_partition.current: Read complete after 0s [id=aws]
data.aws_ssm_parameter.vpc_id: Reading...
module.eks.data.aws_partition.current: Read complete after 0s [id=aws]
data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_subnets: Reading...
module.kms.data.aws_partition.current: Reading...
module.kms.data.aws_partition.current: Read complete after 0s [id=aws]
module.eks.module.kms.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Reading...
data.aws_ssm_parameter.public_subnets: Read complete after 0s [id=/config/qa-k8s-poc/sandbox/vpc-infrastructure/public-subnets]
data.aws_ssm_parameter.public_subnet_3: Read complete after 0s [id=/config/qa-k8s-poc/sandbox/vpc-infrastructure/public-subnet-3]
module.disabled_eks_managed_node_group.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Reading...
data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_subnet_1: Reading...
data.aws_ssm_parameter.intra_subnet_2: Read complete after 0s [id=/config/qa-k8s-poc/sandbox/vpc-infrastructure/intra-subnet-2]
module.disabled_self_managed_node_group.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Reading...
data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_subnets: Read complete after 0s [id=/config/qa-k8s-poc/sandbox/vpc-infrastructure/public-subnets]
data.aws_ssm_parameter.vpc_id: Read complete after 0s [id=/config/qa-k8s-poc/sandbox/vpc-infrastructure/vpc-id]
data.aws_caller_identity.current: Reading...
data.aws_ssm_parameter.public_subnet_2: Read complete after 0s [id=/config/qa-k8s-poc/sandbox/vpc-infrastructure/public-subnet-2]
module.disabled_self_managed_node_group.data.aws_partition.current: Reading...
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["blue"].data.aws_caller_identity.current: Reading...
module.disabled_self_managed_node_group.data.aws_partition.current: Read complete after 0s [id=aws]
data.aws_ssm_parameter.public_subnet_1: Reading...
data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_subnet_1: Read complete after 0s [id=/config/qa-k8s-poc/sandbox/vpc-infrastructure/private-subnet-1]
data.aws_availability_zones.available: Reading...
data.aws_ssm_parameter.public_subnet_1: Read complete after 0s [id=/config/qa-k8s-poc/sandbox/vpc-infrastructure/public-subnet-1]
module.disabled_fargate_profile.data.aws_partition.current: Reading...
module.disabled_fargate_profile.data.aws_partition.current: Read complete after 0s [id=aws]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["green"].data.aws_caller_identity.current: Reading...
data.aws_availability_zones.available: Read complete after 0s [id=eu-west-2]
module.disabled_fargate_profile.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Reading...
module.eks.module.kms.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Read complete after 0s [id=*accountid*]
data.aws_ssm_parameter.intra_subnets: Reading...
module.eks.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Read complete after 0s [id=*accountid*]
module.disabled_eks_managed_node_group.data.aws_partition.current: Reading...
module.disabled_eks_managed_node_group.data.aws_partition.current: Read complete after 0s [id=aws]
module.disabled_eks.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Reading...
data.aws_ssm_parameter.intra_subnets: Read complete after 0s [id=/config/qa-k8s-poc/sandbox/vpc-infrastructure/intra-subnets]
module.kms.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Reading...
module.disabled_eks.module.kms.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Read complete after 0s [id=*accountid*]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["green"].data.aws_partition.current: Reading...
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["green"].data.aws_partition.current: Read complete after 0s [id=aws]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["blue"].data.aws_partition.current: Reading...
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["blue"].data.aws_partition.current: Read complete after 0s [id=aws]
module.disabled_eks.data.aws_partition.current: Reading...
module.disabled_eks.data.aws_partition.current: Read complete after 0s [id=aws]
data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_subnet_2: Reading...
module.disabled_eks_managed_node_group.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Read complete after 0s [id=*accountid*]
module.disabled_eks.module.kms.data.aws_partition.current: Reading...
module.disabled_eks.module.kms.data.aws_partition.current: Read complete after 0s [id=aws]
data.aws_ssm_parameter.intra_subnet_1: Reading...
data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_subnet_2: Read complete after 0s [id=/config/qa-k8s-poc/sandbox/vpc-infrastructure/private-subnet-2]
data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_subnet_3: Reading...
data.aws_caller_identity.current: Read complete after 1s [id=*accountid*]
module.eks.aws_cloudwatch_log_group.this[0]: Refreshing state... [id=/aws/eks/qa-k8s-poc-Cluster/cluster]
module.disabled_self_managed_node_group.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Read complete after 1s [id=*accountid*]
aws_security_group.additional: Refreshing state... [id=sg-0ddadd651c07cad73]
data.aws_ssm_parameter.intra_subnet_1: Read complete after 1s [id=/config/qa-k8s-poc/sandbox/vpc-infrastructure/intra-subnet-1]
module.eks.data.aws_iam_session_context.current: Reading...
data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_subnet_3: Read complete after 1s [id=/config/qa-k8s-poc/sandbox/vpc-infrastructure/private-subnet-3]
module.eks.data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy[0]: Reading...
module.eks.data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy[0]: Read complete after 0s [id=2764486067]
module.eks.aws_security_group.node[0]: Refreshing state... [id=sg-04759c13ed6856cc0]
module.disabled_fargate_profile.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Read complete after 1s [id=*accountid*]
module.eks.aws_security_group.cluster[0]: Refreshing state... [id=sg-0933687d3eb7462ef]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["blue"].data.aws_caller_identity.current: Read complete after 1s [id=*accountid*]
module.eks.aws_iam_role.this[0]: Refreshing state... [id=qa-k8s-poc-Cluster-cluster-20230110184259863000000002]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["green"].data.aws_caller_identity.current: Read complete after 1s [id=*accountid*]
module.disabled_eks.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Read complete after 1s [id=*accountid*]
module.disabled_eks.data.aws_iam_session_context.current: Reading...
module.kms.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Read complete after 1s [id=*accountid*]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["blue"].data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy[0]: Reading...
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["green"].data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy[0]: Reading...
module.kms.data.aws_iam_policy_document.this[0]: Reading...
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["green"].data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy[0]: Read complete after 0s [id=2560088296]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["blue"].data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy[0]: Read complete after 0s [id=2560088296]
module.kms.data.aws_iam_policy_document.this[0]: Read complete after 0s [id=1077172153]
module.kms.aws_kms_key.this[0]: Refreshing state... [id=51a16f6d-fd34-4f79-b750-1e5aee6cb1a8]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["green"].aws_iam_role.this[0]: Refreshing state... [id=green-eks-node-group-2023011018430547080000000c]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["blue"].aws_iam_role.this[0]: Refreshing state... [id=blue-eks-node-group-2023011018430548410000000d]
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.cluster["ingress_nodes_ephemeral_ports_tcp"]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-200464832]
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.cluster["ingress_nodes_443"]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-902431085]
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.cluster["ingress_source_security_group_id"]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-3215013355]
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.node["ingress_nodes_ephemeral"]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-737063987]
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.node["ingress_cluster_4443_webhook"]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-1308494228]
module.eks.data.aws_iam_session_context.current: Read complete after 0s [id=arn:aws:sts::*accountid*:assumed-role/QASreRole/aws-go-sdk-1673428067877551000]
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.node["egress_all"]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-1662029283]
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.node["ingress_source_security_group_id"]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-1683737215]
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.node["ingress_cluster_kubelet"]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-3554252842]
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.node["ingress_self_coredns_tcp"]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-1081401244]
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.node["ingress_cluster_443"]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-1835219689]
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.node["ingress_cluster_9443_webhook"]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-4081148392]
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.node["ingress_self_coredns_udp"]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-3828055155]
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.node["ingress_self_all"]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-424609732]
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.node["ingress_cluster_8443_webhook"]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-2548060707]
module.disabled_eks.data.aws_iam_session_context.current: Read complete after 0s [id=arn:aws:sts::*accountid*:assumed-role/QASreRole/aws-go-sdk-1673428067877551000]
module.kms.aws_kms_alias.this["eks/qa-k8s-poc-aws-alb-controller-qa-k8s-poc-Cluster"]: Refreshing state... [id=alias/eks/qa-k8s-poc-aws-alb-controller-qa-k8s-poc-Cluster]
module.eks.aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.additional["additional"]: Refreshing state... [id=qa-k8s-poc-Cluster-cluster-20230110184259863000000002-2023011018430070560000000a]
module.eks.aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.this["AmazonEKSVPCResourceController"]: Refreshing state... [id=qa-k8s-poc-Cluster-cluster-20230110184259863000000002-20230110184300694600000009]
module.eks.aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.this["AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"]: Refreshing state... [id=qa-k8s-poc-Cluster-cluster-20230110184259863000000002-2023011018430072490000000b]
module.eks.aws_iam_policy.cluster_encryption[0]: Refreshing state... [id=arn:aws:iam::*accountid*:policy/qa-k8s-poc-Cluster-cluster-ClusterEncryption20230110184313822500000016]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["green"].aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.additional["additional"]: Refreshing state... [id=green-eks-node-group-2023011018430547080000000c-20230110184306195800000011]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["blue"].aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.additional["additional"]: Refreshing state... [id=blue-eks-node-group-2023011018430548410000000d-20230110184306298500000012]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["green"].aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.this["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"]: Refreshing state... [id=green-eks-node-group-2023011018430547080000000c-2023011018430617070000000f]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["green"].aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.this["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"]: Refreshing state... [id=green-eks-node-group-2023011018430547080000000c-2023011018430616410000000e]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["blue"].aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.this["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"]: Refreshing state... [id=blue-eks-node-group-2023011018430548410000000d-20230110184306299300000013]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["blue"].aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.this["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"]: Refreshing state... [id=blue-eks-node-group-2023011018430548410000000d-20230110184306309800000014]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["blue"].aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.this["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"]: Refreshing state... [id=blue-eks-node-group-2023011018430548410000000d-20230110184306324700000015]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["green"].aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.this["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"]: Refreshing state... [id=green-eks-node-group-2023011018430547080000000c-20230110184306175400000010]
module.eks.aws_eks_cluster.this[0]: Refreshing state... [id=qa-k8s-poc-Cluster]
module.eks.aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.cluster_encryption[0]: Refreshing state... [id=qa-k8s-poc-Cluster-cluster-20230110184259863000000002-20230110184314107500000017]
module.eks.aws_ec2_tag.cluster_primary_security_group["Environment"]: Refreshing state... [id=sg-091358fdcf58991cf,Environment]
module.eks.aws_ec2_tag.cluster_primary_security_group["Creator"]: Refreshing state... [id=sg-091358fdcf58991cf,Creator]
module.eks.aws_ec2_tag.cluster_primary_security_group["Project"]: Refreshing state... [id=sg-091358fdcf58991cf,Project]
module.eks.data.aws_eks_addon_version.this["coredns"]: Reading...
module.eks.data.aws_eks_addon_version.this["kube-proxy"]: Reading...
module.eks.data.aws_eks_addon_version.this["vpc-cni"]: Reading...
module.eks.aws_ec2_tag.cluster_primary_security_group["Application"]: Refreshing state... [id=sg-091358fdcf58991cf,Application]
module.eks.data.tls_certificate.this[0]: Reading...
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["blue"].aws_launch_template.this[0]: Refreshing state... [id=lt-029f98658fd4d579c]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["green"].aws_launch_template.this[0]: Refreshing state... [id=lt-042af07b1378b110d]
module.eks.data.tls_certificate.this[0]: Read complete after 0s [id=0fec62e3a5b6c39cf9c786f5984abfdb03f2915d]
module.eks.aws_iam_openid_connect_provider.oidc_provider[0]: Refreshing state... [id=arn:aws:iam::*accountid*:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/id/6AC4517F47D7AABAF1E426B0CB58641C]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["blue"].aws_eks_node_group.this[0]: Refreshing state... [id=qa-k8s-poc-Cluster:blue-20230110185401924400000020]
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["green"].aws_eks_node_group.this[0]: Refreshing state... [id=qa-k8s-poc-Cluster:green-20230110185401925100000022]
module.eks.data.aws_eks_addon_version.this["vpc-cni"]: Read complete after 0s [id=vpc-cni]
module.eks.data.aws_eks_addon_version.this["kube-proxy"]: Read complete after 0s [id=kube-proxy]
module.eks.data.aws_eks_addon_version.this["coredns"]: Read complete after 0s [id=coredns]
module.eks.aws_eks_addon.this["vpc-cni"]: Refreshing state... [id=qa-k8s-poc-Cluster:vpc-cni]
module.eks.aws_eks_addon.this["kube-proxy"]: Refreshing state... [id=qa-k8s-poc-Cluster:kube-proxy]
module.eks.aws_eks_addon.this["coredns"]: Refreshing state... [id=qa-k8s-poc-Cluster:coredns]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.eks.kubernetes_config_map_v1_data.aws_auth[0] will be created
  + resource "kubernetes_config_map_v1_data" "aws_auth" {
      + data          = {
          + "mapAccounts" = jsonencode([])
          + "mapRoles"    = <<-EOT
                - "groups":
                  - "system:bootstrappers"
                  - "system:nodes"
                  "rolearn": "arn:aws:iam::*accountid*:role/blue-eks-node-group-2023011018430548410000000d"
                  "username": "system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}"
                - "groups":
                  - "system:bootstrappers"
                  - "system:nodes"
                  "rolearn": "arn:aws:iam::*accountid*:role/green-eks-node-group-2023011018430547080000000c"
                  "username": "system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}"
                - "groups":
                  - "system:masters"
                  "rolearn": "arn:aws:iam::*accountid*:role/QADevelopersRole"
                  "username": "QADevelopersRole"
                - "groups":
                  - "system:masters"
                  "rolearn": "arn:aws:iam::*accountid*:role/QAAdminRole"
                  "username": "QAAdminRole"
                - "groups":
                  - "system:masters"
                  "rolearn": "arn:aws:iam::*accountid*:role/QASreRole"
                  "username": "QASreRole"
                - "groups":
                  - "system:masters"
                  "rolearn": "arn:aws:iam::*accountid*:role/sandbox-eu-west-2-ContinuousDeliverySlavesRole"
                  "username": "sandbox-eu-west-2-ContinuousDeliverySlavesRole"
            EOT
          + "mapUsers"    = jsonencode([])
        }
      + field_manager = "Terraform"
      + force         = true
      + id            = (known after apply)

      + metadata {
          + name      = "aws-auth"
          + namespace = "kube-system"
        }
    }

  # module.kms.aws_kms_key.this[0] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_kms_key" "this" {
        id                                 = "51a16f6d-fd34-4f79-b750-1e5aee6cb1a8"
      ~ policy                             = jsonencode(
          ~ {
              ~ Statement = [
                    {
                        Action    = "kms:*"
                        Effect    = "Allow"
                        Principal = {
                            AWS = "arn:aws:iam::*accountid*:root"
                        }
                        Resource  = "*"
                        Sid       = "Default"
                    },
                  ~ {
                      ~ Principal = {
                          ~ AWS = "arn:aws:sts::*accountid*:assumed-role/QASreRole/aws-go-sdk-1673381797922395000" -> "arn:aws:sts::*accountid*:assumed-role/QASreRole/aws-go-sdk-1673428067877551000"
                        }
                        # (4 unchanged elements hidden)
                    },
                ]
                # (1 unchanged element hidden)
            }
        )
        tags                               = {
            "Application" = "aws-alb-controller"
            "Creator"     = "Terraform via sandbox-qa-k8s-poc-aws-alb-controller"
            "Environment" = "sandbox"
            "Project"     = "qa-k8s-poc"
        }
        # (10 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
module.kms.aws_kms_key.this[0]: Modifying... [id=51a16f6d-fd34-4f79-b750-1e5aee6cb1a8]
module.eks.kubernetes_config_map_v1_data.aws_auth[0]: Creating...
module.kms.aws_kms_key.this[0]: Modifications complete after 4s [id=51a16f6d-fd34-4f79-b750-1e5aee6cb1a8]


Error: The configmap "aws-auth" does not exist

  with module.eks.kubernetes_config_map_v1_data.aws_auth[0],
  on .terraform/modules/eks/main.tf line 527, in resource "kubernetes_config_map_v1_data" "aws_auth":
 527: resource "kubernetes_config_map_v1_data" "aws_auth" {
```

What have a missed here? Many thanks :)

Comment: Based on that output it is clear that this issue is after an allegedly successful `apply` command. Please share the relevant information related to the results of that `apply`.

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard - I have now added the apply output.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check the permissions for the Kubernetes Provider. So the AWS provider in terraform has privileges only upto creating the node and the master plane components. However, attempting to run anything inside the kubernetes is upto the kubernetes provider. If you are using asssuming a role to execute the terraform script then maybe this will help

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data)
  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
    command     = "aws"
    args = [
      "eks",
      "get-token",
      "--role-arn",
      local.assume_role_arn,
      "--cluster-name",
      module.eks.cluster_name
    ]
  }
}
```

Another possible scenario where this error occurs is that your underlying aws-cli version is either old or no aws-cli installed at all.
I experienced this error while deploying kubernetes payloads using Terraform through Github Actions.